# Why can the variable with underline be read without underline in class in php?

Tags: php, class

I have saw too many php class example use the code like this:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $_default = array(
      'page' => 1,
      'perPage' => 10 
    );

    public function __construct()
    {
      $curPage = $this->default['page'];
      $perPage = $this->default['perPage'];
    }
}
```

Why can `$_default` be used via `$this->default` instead of `$this->_default` ?

And which one is recommended?

P.S. If this question is duplicate, please tell me and I will delete it as soon as possible.

Comment: I have no idea where you saw this. But the code is wrong. You can't mix _default and default. See: https://3v4l.org/UBaDW

Comment: @jh1711 I saw it here:[link](https://github.com/lotsofcode/php-array-pagination/blob/master/pagination.class.php)

Comment: That's an issue. Author should remove `_` while defining property `default`. You may report to them.

Comment: Still looks like a mistake to me. But the magic `__get` of that class will prevent the notice about an undefined property, but the constructor does not use the `_default` array; it uses the boolean `false` returned from `__get`.

Comment: @jh1711 So that is a another variable, not `$_default`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private class members are preceded by a single underscore.

For more info:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php

Comment: So if that variable is public, it don't need to have single underscore?